# Solr 8.3 add new replica for a specific collection on new nodes

Tags: kubernetes, solr, autoscaling, solrcloud

I have solr 8.3

I have autoscaling policy configured like this.

```
"cluster-policy": [
    {
      "replica": "<2",
      "collection": "autoscale-test",
      "shard": "#EACH",
      "nodeset": {
        "sysprop.channel": "autoscale"
      }
    }
  ]
```

The collection autoscale-test has replication factor  of 3 and autoAddReplicas enabled.

When I add new nodes (kubernetes pods)  with the  appropriate property, The 2 replicas which are already there on a single node (pod) stay. They are not moved, neither  there is a new replica created.

Looks like the autoscaling policies are not working as documented. Has anyone succeeded in achiving similar results ?